# R: categorizing records based on more than 1 variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to classify records in a table based on their location.  I've divided the area into 9 square of equal width and equal height (width != height), and would like to create a new column where each record is given a label on the basis of which square it falls in.  This is the best I could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

latitude = 10*runif(100)
longitude = 10*runif(100)
locations = data.frame(latitude, longitude)

max_lat <- max(locations$latitude)
min_lat <- min(locations$latitude)
max_lng <- max(locations$longitude)
min_lng <- min(locations$longitude)

grid_num_lat <- 3
grid_num_lng <- 3

step_lat <- (max_lat-min_lat)/grid_num_lat
step_lng <- (max_lng-min_lng)/grid_num_lng

locations <- locations %>%
  mutate(grp_lat = ifelse(latitude <= (min_lat+step_lat), "A", 
                          ifelse(latitude <= (min_lat+(2*step_lat)), "B", 
                                 ifelse(latitude <= (min_lat+(3*step_lat)), "C", "NA")))
         , grp_lng = ifelse(longitude <= (min_lng+step_lng), "1", 
                            ifelse(longitude <= (min_lng+(2*step_lng)), "2", 
                                   ifelse(longitude <= (min_lng+(3*step_lng)), "3", "NA")))
         , grp_loc = paste(grp_lat, grp_lng))
```

While this works for my present purposes, updating the code would be annoying if I wanted to split the area into more or fewer squares.  Surely there's a simpler way to achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try with `cut` i.e `locations %>% mutate(grp_lat = LETTERS[findInterval(latitude, seq_len(3) *(min_lat +step_lat))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a vectorized way with `findInterval`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out1 <- locations %>%
           mutate(grp_lat = LETTERS[findInterval(latitude, 
                          (min_lat + seq_len(3) *step_lat), 
                        rightmost.closed = TRUE)+ 1], 
                 grp_lng = findInterval(longitude, 
                          (min_lng + seq_len(3) *step_lng), 
                     rightmost.closed = TRUE)+ 1,
                  grp_loc = str_c(grp_lat, grp_lng, sep= ' ') )
```

-checking with OP's output

```
all.equal(out$grp_loc, out1$grp_loc)
#[1] TRUE
```